# selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: - drop down item ID,XPATH did not work

Tags: python, selenium

Could someone help me in cracking this down?

This is the element part in website:
`<span id="__xmlview0--__idDateType-arrow" class="sapMSltArrow"></span>`

This is my find element part in python script:

```py
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='__xmlview0--__idDateType-arrow']").click()
```

Error message:

> selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id='__xmlview0--__idDateType-arrow']"}
> (Session info: chrome=92.0.4515.159)

**Edit :**

```
<div id="_xmlview0--__idDateType" data-sap-ui="__xmlview0--__idDateType" style="width:100%;max-width:100%" class="sapMSlt sapMSltDefault sapMSltHoverable sapMSltWithArrow" aria-required="true" aria-labelledby="__xmlview0--filbar-filterItem-___INTERNAL-MyOwnFilterField __xmlview0--__idDateType-label" role="combobox" aria-expanded="false" aria-live="polite" tabindex="0"><label id="__xmlview0--__idDateType-label" for="__xmlview0--__idDateType" class="sapMSltLabel">Fiscal Year</label><span id="__xmlview0--__idDateType-arrow" class="sapMSltArrow"></span></div>
```

Comment: Could you share how you reach to that website, which website you are trying to parse or the whole HTML structure of the page?

Comment: Hi @Muhteva, the webpage I'm using a company proprietry. So couldn't share that. But basically, this is a timesheet webpage.

Comment: XPATH you are using seems correct to me. It would be helpful if you could at least share more information about the HTML structure. Where is this ```span``` exactly?

Comment: '<div id="__xmlview0--__idDateType" data-sap-ui="__xmlview0--__idDateType" style="width:100%;max-width:100%" class="sapMSlt sapMSltDefault sapMSltHoverable sapMSltWithArrow" aria-required="true" aria-labelledby="__xmlview0--filbar-filterItem-___INTERNAL_-MyOwnFilterField __xmlview0--__idDateType-label" role="combobox" aria-expanded="false" aria-live="polite" tabindex="0"><label id="__xmlview0--__idDateType-label" for="__xmlview0--__idDateType" class="sapMSltLabel">Fiscal Year</label><span id="__xmlview0--__idDateType-arrow" class="sapMSltArrow"></span></div>'

Comment: This is another way to reach to that element: ```driver.find_element_by_css_selector("span.sapMSltArrow").click()``` Maybe this could work, don't know. You mentioned that it's a dropdown element. Make sure that it is visible in the webpage. Maybe you have to click on something before trying to locate it.

Comment: You can use direct text to click on it, `//label[text()='Fiscal Year']` code would be : `WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//label[text()='Fiscal Year']"))).click()`

Answer (score 2):

This exception

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element:
```

Implies either one of them, `element locator is not correct`, `element is not rendered properly`, `element is in iframe.`

Detail illustration below

1. Element `locator` is **not** `correct`, or `Element is dynamic in nature` `i.e. element locator id`, `class_name` are getting `generated` by server by using `javascript` frameworks.

**Solutions**

try to use a `reliable locator`. which may be having a stable  `preceding-sibling` or `following-sibling` or `ancestor` or `descendant` node. And based on the mentioned node, try to use xpath to reach to the desired element.

Always check in `HTML DOM`, if we have unique entry or not for the element we wanna interact with.

**Steps to checks :-**

Press `F12` in `Chrome` -> go to `element` section -> do a `CTRL  + F` -> then paste the locator and see, if the desired element is getting highlighted or not, if it getting highlighted, Do we have unique entry 1/1 or not  ?

2. Element is not `rendered completely/partial` loaded, and you are trying to interact with it.

**Solution**

Basically, a sleep will help us here. You can try to put `time.sleep(5)` here to just debug and if that works, then later it can be implemented via `Explicit waits`.

**Example :-**

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, ""))).click()
```

**Imports :-**

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

3. Element is in `iframe/frame/frameset`

**Solutions**

Check for any `iframe` that could be a `parent/ancestor node` to the `node` we want to **interact** with. if it happens to be, you need to `switch the driver focus to iframe first` and then can interact with the **desired element.**

**Code to switch to iframe :**

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH, "")))
```

after switch to the iframe, you can interact with the either `driver.find_element` or `Explicit waits` as mentioned above.

Actual problem to this **specific ticket :**

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//label[text()='Fiscal Year']"))).click()
```

Comment: With WebDriverWait, it works fine!!!